# MQTT broker for Android

Tags: android, mqtt

Does anyone know of an MQTT broker that runs on an Android smartphone? I tried to Google and found nothing, and on the app store there seems to be only one app with just 10 downloads, so I'm not sure how well it works.

Comment: Why would you like to run a MQTT broker on Android?

Comment: I'm working on a project that may require that multiple clients on the phone talk to each other using MQTT. The same type of clients talk to each other from one device to another using an external MQTT broker, so from the reuse point of view and the requirement that they talk via MQTT, I (think I) really need an MQTT broker.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add these dependencies to the gradle

```
    dependencies{
   compile 'io.moquette:moquette-netty-parser:0.8.1'
    compile 'io.moquette:moquette-broker:0.8.1'
    compile 'io.moquette:moquette-parser-commons:0.8.1'
}
```

And use

```
io.moquette.server.Server server = new io.moquette.server.Server();
server.startServer();
```

to start broker server. the default URI is `tcp://localhost:1883`

For me `server.startServer();` gave me exception as it is unable to create a file `BrokerConstants.DEFAULT_MOQUETTE_STORE_MAP_DB_FILENAME`.
So, I changed the destination of the `BrokerConstants.DEFAULT_MOQUETTE_STORE_MAP_DB_FILENAME`
using this code below code and it worked for me.

```
     try {
         MemoryConfig memoryConfig = new MemoryConfig(new Properties());
memoryConfig.setProperty(BrokerConstants.PERSISTENT_STORE_PROPERTY_NAME, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + BrokerConstants.DEFAULT_MOQUETTE_STORE_MAP_DB_FILENAME);
    server.startServer(memoryConfig); 
        // server.startServer();//is not working due to DEFAULT_MOQUETTE_STORE_MAP_DB_FILENAME; 
        Log.d(TAG,"Server Started");
         }
         catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
         catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
```

And Use Paho libraries for android

```
compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.0'
compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
```

To create a client and connect to `tcp://localhost:1883` and subscribe for a topic and start publishing and receiving messages.

[moquette](https://github.com/andsel/moquette) library for [android](https://github.com/technocreatives/moquette).

Comment: I have tried this,but this keeps on crashing my app without showing any errors.could you help me with this?

Comment: Now it does not crash the app but instead cannot connect to the server.How do i start the server at tcp://localhost:1883?

Comment: use `io.moquette.server.Server server = new io.moquette.server.Server();
server.startServer();` to start service run this code in service or a thread.

Comment: @DhruvMarwha access it here - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=server.com.mqtt

Comment: @anshulkatta Thank You.I'll check it out surely.When did you make this app?

Comment: Hello @Tej i mean it is working fine though but i am unable to access My Android broker from outside of Android app, i am able to create client within broker app, weather i access it with localhost or with manual ip of device it does work, but from out side of Android device if i try to access connection refused, or connection time out i am facing, could you please enlighten?

Comment: getting error : Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> []
    W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0      at server.startServer(memoryConfig);

Comment: BTW, I am trying to configure it in Android Things (IOT OS).

Comment: Is there any workaround for missing distribution tar file for moquette?
when i try to download, it redirects me to a dead link with "Forbidden!" message.
https://github.com/technocreatives/moquette#1-minute-set-up

Answer (score 7):

> I have developed an App specifically for this , please download here -
>
> It has inbuilt broker and client too..all for free , connect your
>   devices to android phone via hotspot or wifi.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=server.com.mqtt

Comment: why is this answer downvoted? Because he did the app himself? IMHO this answers the original question perfectly.. And I'm giving a try to this app right now

Comment: Can you share the code in github and make it open source it will be very useful. Thank you.

Comment: +1 on open sourcing the code. This is really a cool app. Thanks for building it. If there is no internet, then the IP address is 0.0.0.0:1883. I think this makes sense but if I have other devices connected to a phone over the hotspot, then I would want the IP address to be 192.168.43.1:1883 where 192.168.43.1 is the default IP address for the hotspot. This IP address may have been changed by mobile phone manufacturer sometimes.

Comment: @anshulkatta: Is your app built on the Moquette lib?

Comment: @Markus not entirely but a very stripped down version of Moquette, i think its worth noting now that mqtt is available via cloud so worth looking  in that way rather than broker on android

Comment: @anshulkatta: Thanks for the info! I have a special use case where I want to have the broker on the Android device

Answer (score 3):

You can run the mosquitto mqtt broker within the Termux terminal.

- Install [Termux](https://termux.com/) using e.g. [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/de/packages/com.termux/)
- Open/run the Termux Terminal emulator
- Install mosquitto

  `pkg install mosquitto`
- Start mosquitto within the terminal

  `mosquitto`

That's it. The server will listen on the default port 1883.
Configuration see at [mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/).

Comment: The question makes it super clear that it's about an MQTT broker "runs on an Android smartphone"

Answer (score 2):

Here is an MQTT broker library I have adapted to Android: https://github.com/interaktionsbyran/moquette
You'll have to make your own Android app though, it is just a library.

Comment: can you help in making a sample app using moquette for Android ?