# android things MQTT broker

Tags: java, android, mqtt, android-things, android-things-console

so I'm building a home automation project and I want the main server/processing hub to be a Raspberry Pi 3 running Android things.

The problem currently is that I'm having a hard time installing/coding/running an MQTT server on the Raspberry Pi 3 when it's running the Android things OS.

Does any one know a method to install and run an MQTT broker along side an android things "app" or integrating the MQTT broker into the project code?

I have been looking at this post
 [MQTT broker for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623707/mqtt-broker-for-android)

but with no luck as my project won't compile when including some of the dependencies :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623707/mqtt-broker-for-android

Comment: I have trayed the things suggested in that link with no luck my project won't compile when including the dependencies

Comment: Then perhaps you should ask a separate question where you provide an [mcve] showing what you tried and providing the compile error.