# MQTT Broker for Cyclone X4+

Tags: mqtt, broker

I have a android box around (Sunvision Cyclone X4+) which has some good specification, I wonder if I can use it as a MQTT Broker as this is small rather powerful enough for this (I Guess), but I could not find anything that could help me on that

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MQTT broker for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623707/mqtt-broker-for-android)

Comment: HI... Thanks yes it might be duplicated... I have tried to install the MQTT Broker APP, but no success, will try again today, thanks